# difference between "take away" and "abolish"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

What is the difference between "take away" & "abolish"? can they convey the same meaning? I looked up to dictionaries, while didn't get a good result.

> **Take away:** remove
>   **Abolish:** To do away with; put an end to

for example:

> 1.we should take the former rules away.
>   2.we should abolish the rules.

does "1" equal to "2"? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: They can mean the same, but they might not.  If I take away your supper that does not mean that supper has been abolished.

Comment: when will they have the same meaning? it will be nice if you can give me some examples.

Comment: If I take away your supper, you don't get to eat supper tonight.  If I abolish your supper, you don't get to eat supper ever again.  I'd say it's pretty rare for "abolish" to be as weak as "take away".

Comment: oh, that's very clear.  thank you for your answer!!!!

Comment: On the other hand, if a government "takes away" something like a pension for military veterans, they can be said to have "abolished" it.  In one case "take away" refers to only one instance, in the other case it refers to every instance.

Comment: The real difference is that "abolish" implies that there is some recognized authority that has "established" the thing being abolished. For example parents, a club, or the government. I could "take away" (steal) an apple from you. So for "take away" there is no recognized authority.

Comment: [Here is a question that matches yours, like 100%](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/take-away-abolish.3116173/)

Answer (score 1):

*Abolish* is *generally* done to an idea, such as an Institution, Practice or  System. President Lincoln *abolished* the institution of slavery. In contemporary society, we want to *abolish* the idea of *hate crime*.

Parents do not *abolish* an unruly child's toy - the toy gets *taken away*. The implication is that *good behavior* will lead to the toy's reinstatement. Good behavior (on anyone's part) will never lead to the re-institutionalization of slavery.

Great word that, re-institutionalization.

Answer (score 0):

to take away = to remove something;
to abolish = to leave behind == to remove/distance yourself from something;

so, in comparison to the upper example: parents can either remove a toy as punishement or abolish the spoiled child by leaving it in the forrest.

Comment: To abolish is to get rid of, not to leave behind.

Comment: This is nonsense.  A complete misunderstaning of the word *abolish*.